# Working with Ubuntu in Docker from Windows Along with Strict Antivirus

Tags: apt, 20.04, 22.04, security, docker

I am trying to work with an Ubuntu Docker Container from my Windows 11 OS.

I am using work PC and they have very strict Antivirus and Security causing me to have blocked IPs whenever I do `apt-update` from within the Ubuntu container.

I get this error:

```
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Get:5 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/sbsa  InRelease [1579 B]
Ign:6 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/sbsa  InRelease
Get:7 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/sbsa  Release [562 B]
Err:5 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/sbsa  InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC
Get:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/sbsa  Release.gpg [833 B]
Get:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/sbsa  Packages [1232 B]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/sbsa  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC
E: The repository 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/sbsa  InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So my questions are: Is there a way I can work with Ubuntu Docker ***Safely***? also, I read somewhere that Ubuntu/Linux is prone to hacking compared to Windows and has open ports but I am not sure of the sources neither do I have good knowledge in Security, Can someone validate this as well?

Appreciate all help & Thanks!

Comment: Not precisely Ubuntu version 18, I am facing this issue with all versions of Ubuntu, let me update the tags.

Comment: The error in the post is still for 18.04. What was the error for 22.04 or 20.04?

Comment: Still getting same error; a series of blocked IPs, using this Image: 11.2.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04.

Comment: I can access `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/InRelease` just fine, so ask your IT department to unblock it. If its a necessary part of your work, they should be able to do it.

Comment: *"I read somewhere that Ubuntu/Linux is prone to hacking compared to Windows"*. You know, people write all sorts of silly things. Anyway, if you need Docker in your work, talk to your boss or IT to get access. We can't really do anything concerning your workplace.

Comment: Log a call with your IT department to unblock the IP addresses for updates